# im Folgenden vs. im folgenden (alte Rechtschreibung)

Tags: spelling, capitalization

Laut [Korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/im_folgenden.shtml) wird *im Folgenden* so geschrieben:

**bis 1996**
im folgenden (weiter unten)
im Folgenden (in den folgenden Ausführungen)

**seit 1996**
im Folgenden

Wie wurde vor 1996 zwischen den beiden Schreibweisen unterschieden? Für mich scheint "weiter unten" und "in den folgenden Ausführungen" dasselbe zu sein. Kann jemand Beispiele geben für die Unterschiede?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Im Duden gab es die Regel

> **R65** Substantivisch gebrauchte Adjektive und Partizipien werden groß geschrieben.

Gemäß dieser Regel wurde *im Folgenden* groß geschrieben.

Zur Regel R65 gab es dann aber mehrere Ausnahmen:

> - Adjektive und Partizipien, die durch einen Artikel der Form nach substantiviert sind, werden klein geschrieben, wenn die jeweilige Fügung durch ein bloßes Adjektiv, Partizip oder Adverb ersetzt werden kann.
> - Adjektive und Partizipien, die in festen Verbindungen [mit Verben] stehen, werden klein geschrieben, auch wenn sie der Form nach substantiviert sind.
> - Adjektive in unveränderlichen Wortpaaren werden klein geschrieben, auch wenn sie scheinbar wie Substantive gebraucht werden.
> - Ein Adjektiv oder Partizip mit vorangehendem Artikel u. ä. wird klein geschrieben, wenn es Beifügung (Attribut) zu einem vorangehenden oder nachstehenden Substantiv ist.
> - Ein Adjektiv oder Partizip [mit vorangehendem Artikel u. ä.] wird klein geschrieben, wenn es wie ein Pronomen (Fürwort) gebraucht wird.

Konnte man *im Folgenden* z.B. mit *weiter unten* ersetzen, griff die erste Ausnahme, und *im folgenden* wurde klein geschrieben.

Answer (score 6):

Es ist schwierig, nach so langer Zeit noch Informationen zur Rechtschreibung vor 1996 zu finden. Zumal ja gerade solche Stolperfallen (wann "Folgenden" groß oder klein geschrieben wird) durch die Reform bereinigt und vereinheitlicht werden sollten. Was ich für die Unterscheidung bis 1996 gefunden habe, ist:

Ein Beispiel für die Großschreibung im Sinne von "in den folgenden Ausführungen" ist:

> Wenn ein Lehrer darauf hinweist, dass er in der Unterrichtsstunde noch bestimmte Dinge ansprechen oder vermitteln wird, sagt er: "Das werden wir uns im Folgenden noch genauer anschauen."

Ein Beispiel für die Kleinschreibung im Sinne von "weiter unten" ist/war beispielsweise ein typischer Vertragstext:

> Die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen (im folgenden „AGB“ genannt) gelten ...

Aber wie gesagt, man sieht, dass die Unterscheidung sehr diffizil war und deshalb war die Vereinheitlichung bei der Reform durchaus angebracht.

Answer (score 5):

Im allgemeinen (!) hat man *im folgenden* nach guter alter Schreibung meistes klein geschrieben. Des weiteren (!) konnte man aber, wenn von einem sehr konkreten *Folgenden* die Rede war, auch *im Folgenden* schreiben. Im großen und ganzen (!) haben sich die neuen Regeln durchgesetzt, aber im besonderen (!) und im einzelnen (!) halten sich hier und da noch ein paar Nester von unbeugsamen Galliern, die von der alten Orthographie nicht weichen möchten. Sie glauben, dass Deutschlernende mit den neuen Regeln im dunkeln (!) gelassen werden und dass die alten Regeln klarer waren: *Im Dunkeln* schrieb man groß, wenn es ein konkretes Dunkel war, in dem man etwa spazieren ging, und klein, wenn es ein metaphorisches war, in dem man belassen wurde.